# React native grid of boxes that fill all phone screen size, when swiped will dissapear

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

[image: Grid Box]

How can i create grid of boxes like in the image for React Native, and the boxes will fill all screen sizes of phones?

And for each box, if get swipe gesture by the user, it will dissapear from the screen, but all untouched boxes remain in the same coordinate/place. 
If all boxes dissapear, then the program will continue.

So far i have tried this method to display the boxes: `

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
  }
  createBoxes = numberOfBoxes => {
    let boxes = [];
    // Outer loop to create parent
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; i++) {
      boxes.push(
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={i}
          style={styles.box}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("number "+ i);
          }}
        >
          <Text>{i}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }

    return boxes;
  };
  render() {
    const boxHeight = 29;
    const height = Math.ceil(Dimensions.get("window").height);

    let totalBox = Math.round(height / boxHeight) * 9; //9 is the number of box on screen
    console.log(height, boxHeight, totalBox);

    return <View style={styles.container}>{this.createBoxes(totalBox)}</View>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    alignItems: "flex-start"
  },
  box: {
    width: "10%",
    height: 25,
    margin: 2,
    backgroundColor: "powderblue"
  }
});
```

`
But the result is not proper for different phone ratio (16:9 results in ok, but 18:9 have a bit of space left on the bottom of the phone)

The 16:9 result fits the screen perfectly (Android):
[image: 16:9 boxes]

But in iOS the width is not perfect, still have some blank space on the right side: 
[image: iOS result]

How to achieve so?

Comment: I have had the same issue. Try reducing width by 1 or 2 on ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your container style by adding below code as follows:

```
justifyContent: "space-evenly"
```

Please find updated code below:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
  }
  createBoxes = numberOfBoxes => {
    let boxes = [];
    // Outer loop to create parent
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; i++) {
      boxes.push(
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={i}
          style={styles.box}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("number "+ i);
          }}
        >
          <Text>{i}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }

    return boxes;
  };
  render() {
    const boxHeight = 29;
    const height = Math.ceil(Dimensions.get("window").height);

    let totalBox = Math.round(height / boxHeight) * 9; //9 is the number of box on screen
    console.log(height, boxHeight, totalBox);

    return <View style={styles.container}>{this.createBoxes(totalBox)}</View>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
  },
  box: {
    width: "9%",
    height: 25,
    margin: '0.5%',
    aspectRatio: 1,
    backgroundColor: "powderblue"
  }
});
```

Comment: no, it is not working since this only spread the content to the middle instead of filling the screen space.

Comment: @winadiw, I have updated the answer. Please check the same.

Comment: thanks for the help, not quite perfect but it gets the job done.